# Can using System Restore point, while turning the internet temporarily off, recover deleted IMAP messages?

Tags: imap, outlook-2010, system-restore

Lets say a person is using Outlook, and has their email setup as IMAP, and later the server where the mail is located, well, lets just say all the emails are deleted permanently.

Would it be possible to turn off the internet for that computer, restore to an earlier point using Windows restore, open Outlook, copy the messages and folders to a local folder, and then turn the internet back on, wait for the email to sync, and then copy the messages back into the email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. System restore only handles system settings, not personal data (which includes e-mail). If you have a backup elsewhere, you could use that backup.